# If-then regex: if pattern matches in a line then match another regex

Tags: regex

Couldn't find this exact case anywhere. Many similar examples but for some reason mine isn't working.

Trying to accomplish:
Within each line that contains AddMember, match all text from after the 2nd quote character to the end of the line

After lots of research I've gotten this far:

`(?(?=.*\b(AddMember)\b.*\n)[^\"]+[^\"]+\n)`

`.*\b(AddMember)\b.*\n`: matches all the correct lines

`[^\"]+[^\"]+\n`: matches correctly after the 2nd quote char

Tried to if-then them together with this structure

`(?(?=ifthis)thenthis)`

but doesn't match anything.

Example string:

```
foo.AddMember("bar");
fu.AddMember("bur", test);
```

Should match

```
);
, test);
```

Very curious as to what's wrong! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd like to nominate the above comment as the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using PHP/PCRE. Why do you need a conditional? Just match

```
\bAddMember\b[^"]*"[^"]*"\K.*
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8LCreT/1) (used [\K to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match).
Or just [use a capture group for extraction](https://regex101.com/r/8LCreT/2) which works in most regex flavors.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern works on your examples:

```
(?<=\bAddMember\b[^"]*"[^"]*")(.*)
```

This uses a lookbehind assertion, meaning you want AddMember"" before the actual match, while you used a lookahead assertion.

Cheers

Comment: Okay that sounds like it would work, but the tester I am using posts an error on the *'s saying "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width"

Comment: (?<=\bAddMember\b[^"])(.*) matches successfully on everything after the first quote, so I think the quantifiers might not be necessary. Just need to find a workaround to include the 2nd quote in the lookback.